# Different authentication on GET and POST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I've been following a spring security example but I cannot make sense of it. A simple RestController replying hello on a GetMapping("/hello") with a 200 status code. Once I change it to a PostMapping I receive a 401 for the same credentials sent.

Seems I am missing something fundamental here as I would expect both requests to return a 200 status code.

The security config:

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                List.of(
                        User.withUsername("john")
                                .password("12345")
                                .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")
                                .build(),
                        User.withUsername("jane")
                                .password("12345")
                                .authorities("ROLE_MANAGER")
                                .build()
                )
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

The RestController with the following get mapping returns 200 for this call:

`curl -v -u john:12345 localhost:8080/hello`

and this mapping:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

The RestController with the following post mapping returns 401 for this call:

`curl -X POST -v -u john:12345 localhost:8080/hello`

and this mapping:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @PostMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's CSRF protection comes enabled by default in Spring Security. `POST` requests are affected by this behavior.

Disable it by doing:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend simply disabling CSRF. Check out the [beginning of this video](https://springone.io/2021/sessions/spring-security-5-5) (3:40) from the recent SpringOne conference on what happens when you do this.

Comment: I think he didn't recommend it but showed the solution to the issue at hand. But you are right, definitely not a solution in production environments. I was following the book and the chapter for csrf came later.

Comment: Wow, friends. Actually, my mistake to post such a small answer with no explanation whatsoever. My point was only trying to fast ""fix"" OP's problem. Yes, I do know what happens when you disable CSRF. @1174 there's no problem if you want to mark Steve's answer as the solution. His answer is more complete and send references of possible problems of having CSRF disabled as well as references of how to work with Spring's CSRF protection. No problem if you want to unmark my answer and mark Steve's one.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Matheus Cirillo, [CSRF protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#csrf) is [enabled by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-csrf-configure).

It's tempting to want to disable CSRF protection since we're using a restful api, but [consider what happens](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#csrf-when) if you're using a browser-based single page application to interact with the server. The same authenticated session is still available in the browser, and the application is still vulnerable to a CSRF attack.

You can find [some examples of how to work with csrf protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-csrf-using) in your own application in the docs. In a restful api, you can also [provide an endpoint that returns the csrf token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#mvc-csrf-resolver) in a header or a response parameter.